# How does the federated login on stackoverflow work? Is there an available library that is as refined?

Tags: authentication, registration

The quick login/no registration of stackoverflow is one of its finest features. I'm just curious if there's an off-the-shelf solution for providing this service.

Has anybody seen anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called OpenID. Anybody can define an OpenID, and anybody can use any OpenID for authentication. Visit http://openid.net/ for details.